# keras низкая точность нейронной сети

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, keras

Сегодня начал изучать нейронные сети и придумал себе следующую задачу:

> Есть группа в ВК, у нее есть статистика, которую можно выгрузить в
>   виде .xls файла. Файл имеет следующий вид: [image] Всего 844
>   строки, но меня интересует только половина с параметром views
>   (получается 422 строки) Я хочу по этой статистике предсказать
>   количество просмотров группы в определённый день (в таблице обозначен
>   как time)

По одному из туториалов я набросал следующий код:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LeakyReLU, BatchNormalization, Activation
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.optimizers import Nadam
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Подготовка датасетов
db = pd.read_excel('db.xls')
x = db.get('time').values[::-2]  # 422 всего
y = db.get('val').values[::-2]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

opt = Nadam(lr=0.001)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.9, patience=5, min_lr=0.000001, verbose=1)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'], loss='mse')

history = model.fit(x[:300], y[:300], epochs=10000, batch_size=300, verbose=1, validation_data=(x[300:], y[300:]),
                    callbacks=[reduce_lr], shuffle=True)
print(model.predict(np.array([43248])))
```

Но при обучении сети у нее низкая точность, вот вывод последних строк при обучении:

```
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 10us/step - loss: 232.2393 - acc: 0.0333 - val_loss: 124.9310 - val_acc: 0.0492
Epoch 10000/10000

300/300 [==============================] - 0s 10us/step - loss: 232.2376 - acc: 0.0333 - val_loss: 124.9555 - val_acc: 0.0492
[[38.514076]]
```

Это меньше 3х процентов (если я правильно понимаю единицы измерения).

Что я пробовал: 
 1. Добавить еще один слой (64 нейрона, уже есть в коде)
 2. Менять параметры для количества эпох

Изменения приводили к улучшениям, но они были несерьезными, не выше 0.04

Вопрос: как мне улучшить показатели? Какие ошибки я мог допустить при проектировании сети?

Answer (score 2):

1. При обучении сети принято переводить входные данные из абсолютной шкалы на отрезок [-1; 1] или [0; 1];
2. Попробуйте нелинейные функции активации;
3. Попробуйте различные алгоритмы обучения;
4. Если начиная с какой-либо эпохи погрешность обучения падает, а погрешность обобщения возрастает, попробуйте уменьшить количество эпох. Возможно ваша сеть переобучается;
5. Возможно, в ваших данных попросту нет закономерностей, которые можно выявить с помощью нейросетей (либо их вообще нет). Нельзя, например, по росту человека определить, сколько у него будет детей.

Как видите, обучение нейросети происходит методом проб и ошибок, поэтому точного алгоритма и сочетания параметров вам никто точно не посоветует. Необходимо пробовать различные наборы параметров, алгоритмы, наблюдать за поведением сети и исходя из этого делать выводы. Заранее определить, какая именно сеть нужна для той или иной задачи, невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ваши данные действительно не имеют связи! 
Что бы сделать вывод по представленным данным, нужно что бы как минимум данные были за несколько лет, а так же правильнее считать не дату а день в году. 
От себя могу посоветовать добавить параметр день недели.